# Crear un usuario nuevo a partir de un modelo de usuario extendido en Django

Tags: django, django-models

estoy trabajando con el modelo de usuarios de Django y tuve que extenderlo usando una relacion `OneToOne` con el modelo `User` para añadirle 2 campos mas. La duda me surge cuando quiero crear un nuevo usuario. Probe llamando al modelo `User` de Django pero no funciona y pruebo llamando a mi modelo extendido `Usuarios` pero tampoco funciona. Alguien sabe como hay que referirse al modelo para que funcione? Muchas gracias!

Mi models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
# Create your models here.

class Usuario(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    id_empresa = models.IntegerField()
    telefono = models.IntegerField()
```

Mi views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import Usuario
from .forms import CrearUsuario

# Create your views here.

def crear_usuario(request):
    crear_usuario = CrearUsuario()
    return render(request, "crear_usuario.html", {'crear_usuario':crear_usuario})

def agregar_usuario(request):
    form = CrearUsuario(request.POST)
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.is_valid():
        username = form.cleaned_data['username']
        password = form.cleaned_data['password']
        email = form.cleaned_data['email']
        nombre = form.cleaned_data['nombre']
        apellido = form.cleaned_data['apellido']
        telefono = form.cleaned_data['telefono']
        id_empresa = form.cleaned_data['id_empresa']
        
        user = Usuario(username=username, password=password, email=email, first_name=nombre, last_name=apellido, telefono=telefono, id_empresa=id_empresa)
        
        user.save()
        return redirect('/usuarios/')
```

Comment: Existen dos vistas en tu archivo, a lo que alcanzó a entender, tu primera vista renderiza el formulario y la segunda acepta la información del formulario, sin embargo no es suficiente información para determinar el problema. Posiblemente el prolema sea que no estes mandando la información a la vista correcta(tu segunda vista), otra opción es que el formulario tenga sobrescrito algunos de sus métodos y por eso no funcione. Te recomiendo que verifiques esa parte y subas más información sobre las urls y a que ruta estas mandando el formulario, lo habitual es juntar esas dos vistas en una.

Comment: @SergioC Hola Sergio, recurrí a este método porque necesitaba datos adicionales en la tabla de usuarios de la base de datos que la que trae Django por defecto, mi idea es recurrir a los datos a través del request.user, por ende me decanté por esta opción, aunque estoy explorando los otros métodos existentes.
De cualquier forma, ya entendí como se graban los usuarios, el problema es que no puedo acceder mediante el request.user como a mi me gustaría, porque en si no hay como tal una relación. Vos sabés como podría hacer para hacer uso de eso?

Comment: Creo entender que tu problema está al intentar acceder a la información del modelo `Usuario` desde el objeto `request.user`, si es así, entonces la solución es `request.user.usuario`. Creo que la mejor opción es cambiar el nombre a tu modelo Usuario por algo más habitual como Profile, esto evitará confusiones entre los nombres de modelos Usuario/User.

Comment: Hola Sergio, es exactamente lo que busco, quiero acceder al modelo `Usuario` desde el `request.user`, pero con el método que utilizaste no me funciono, intente hacer `request.user.usuario.id_empresa` por ejemplo, pero no funcionó. Sabes porque puede ser?